# How can I have references to several counters in a formatted way with \ref{}?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I have two counters in my document, `counterA` and `counterB`.

I would like the references `\ref{}` in my document to be printed as `1.a)` or `2.`, etc. where the digit refers to `counterA` and the letter to `counterB`.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{counterA} 
\setcounter{counterA}{0}

\newcounter{counterB}
\setcounter{counterB}{0}


\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterB}
\label{First_Label}

I get: \ref{Second_Label}. I would like \textbf{2.}\,b)

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie.


\bigskip
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterB}
\label{Second_Label}

I get: \ref{First_Label}. I would like \textbf{1.}\,a)

Morbi nec nibh nulla. Cras posuere erat vitae lacus convallis, ut consequat urna dignissim. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time one creates a counter variable named, say, `counterB`, with a `\newcounter` instruction, LaTeX sets up a macro called `\p@counterB` that can be used to "prefix" some other information to the label for the sake of creating a cross-reference. I.e., you could type

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@counterB{\thecounterA.}
\makeatother
```

to prefix LaTeX's representation of the current value of `counterA` plus a `.` to LaTeX's representation of the value of `counterB`.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}
\renewcommand\thecounterA{\arabic{counterA}} % arabic numbering
\renewcommand\thecounterB{\alph{counterB})}  % alphabetic numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@counterB{\thecounterA.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% need to increment the counters via \refstepcounter
\refstepcounter{counterA} \label{refA}
\refstepcounter{counterB} \label{refB}
Here's a cross-reference to item \ref{refB}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The best would be to redefine both `\thecounterA` and `\thecounterB`, so that if `\ref{}`refers to one or to the other, the result will be the same.

Comment: I understood your setup to be as follows: `counterA` is the upper-level or primary variable, and `counterB` is the secondary or subordinate counter. Is that not the case? By the way, you're free to define `\thecounterA` and `\thecounterB` (the "looks" of the individual counters) any way you wish. The MWE simply mimicked the numbering styles you indicated in your query.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command:

```
\renewcommand{\thecounterB}{\textbf{\thecounterA}.\alph{counterB})}
```

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{counterA} 
\setcounter{counterA}{0}

\newcounter{counterB}
\setcounter{counterB}{0}

\renewcommand{\thecounterB}{\textbf{\thecounterA}.\alph{counterB})}
\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterB}
\label{First_Label}

I get: \ref{Second_Label}. I would like \textbf{2.}\,b)

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie.


\bigskip
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\refstepcounter{counterB}
\label{Second_Label}

I get: \ref{First_Label}. I would like \textbf{1.}\,a)

Morbi nec nibh nulla. Cras posuere erat vitae lacus convallis, ut consequat urna dignissim. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do we know that `\ref{}` will refer to `counterB` rather than `counterA`?

Comment: @Colas: The latest `\refstepcounter` before `\label` sets the counter for `\label`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Good to know!