# How can I explicitly ask a \label{} command to refer to a given counter?

Tags: counters

### Question

In a comment [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166304/8323), I learnt that

> The latest `\refstepcounter` before `\label` sets the counter for `\label`

**Is it possible to explicitly ask a `\label{}` command to refer to a given counter?**

I see two cases where this could be useful:

1. there are several counters and you want to be sure which one is chosen.
2. the value of the counter is set *via* `\setcounter`.

### Code and picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{counterA} \setcounter{counterA}{0}

\refstepcounter{counterA}
\label{First_Label}
I get: \ref{Second_Label}. I would like 99.

\bigskip
\setcounter{counterA}{99}
\label{Second_Label}
I get: \ref{First_Label}. I would like 1.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I understand the question, but can you provide a simple use case with expected output (along the lines of a MWE)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\labelcounter[2]{\begingroup
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \label{#2}\endgroup}
\newcommand*\refsetcounter[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  }
\makeatother
```

The line with `\protected@edef` is taken from the definition of `\refstepcounter`. Usage:

```
\labelcounter{equation}{eq:123}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\labelcounter[2]{\begingroup
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \label{#2}\endgroup}
\newcommand*\refsetcounter[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection{Bla}

\begin{equation}a+b\end{equation}

\subsection{Blabla}

\labelcounter{equation}{eq-test}
\label{sect-test}

Should be 0.2: \ref{sect-test}
\\
Should be 1: \ref{eq-test}

\end{document}
```

In your example, the variant with `\refsetcounter` would be more useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\labelcounter[2]{\begingroup
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \label{#2}\endgroup}
\newcommand*\refsetcounter[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{counterA} \setcounter{counterA}{0}

\refstepcounter{counterA}
\label{First_Label}
I get: \ref{Second_Label}. I would like 99.

\bigskip
\refsetcounter{counterA}{99}
\label{Second_Label}
I get: \ref{First_Label}. I would like 1.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\addtocounter{foo}{-1}\refstepcounter{foo}\label{mylabel}
```

will associate the label `mylabel` with the current value of the counter `foo`.